# Google Contacts API nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-contacts-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I've been looking through the Google NodeJS API docs, but I don't see one listed for the Contacts API.  Am I missing something or is that not included in the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google NodeJS API for Google Contacts API, the links below maybe could help you out:

https://github.com/jimib/nodejs-google-contacts

https://github.com/elentok/gcontacts

https://github.com/mattnull/node-googlecontacts

Comment: Thanks!  Where did you see that in the api documentation though?

Comment: I didn't see that in the doc ether. Hope the links can help you out.

Comment: Ok, np, and it definitely did~

Answer (score 3):

Google's official API for NodeJS doesn't use Contacts API. They use instead the People API. If you need to access "Other Contacts", you will need Contacts API.

You can still connect with Contacts API using the [official googleapis library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#supported-apis) if you're already using it for other purposes by sending a request to the Contacts API after creating the auth client. If you're not using the googleapis library, it might be an overkill, and it's better to use the other libraries suggested by other answer.

Given that you already have the access token of the user (e.g. if you generated it using [Passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport), here's the code:

```
const {google} = require("googleapis");
const authObj = new google.auth.OAuth2({
    access_type: 'offline',
    clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
});
```

Refresh access token automatically before it expires

```
authObj.on('tokens', (tokens) => {
    const access_token = tokens.access_token
    if (tokens.refresh_token){
        this.myTokens.refreshToken = tokens.refresh_token
        // save refresh token in the database if it exists
    }
        this.myTokens.accessToken = tokens.access_token       
        // save new access token (tokens.access_token)
}
authObj.setCredentials({
    access_token:this.myTokens.accessToken,
    refresh_token:this.myTokens.refreshToken,
});
```

Make the request to Contacts API:

```
authObj.request({
    headers:{
        "GData-Version":3.0
    },
    params:{
        "alt":"json",
        //"q":"OPTIONAL SEARCH QUERY",
        //"startindex":0
        "orderby":"lastmodified",
        "sortorder":"descending",
    },
    url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"
}).then( response => {
    console.log(response); // extracted contacts
});
```